# Como obter o total de combinações entre dois datasets e a soma de seus atributos?

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho dois datasets (freio e cambio). Tanto o data set de freios quanto o de cambios possuem atributos (Força, Aero, Grip e Rely).Eu gostaria de obter o total de combinações entre esses datasets, e a soma de seus atributos. No exemplo acima coloquei os dois datasets com duas peças cada e também uma exemplo de como gostaria de visualizar o resultado na tabela "Resultado esperado". Essa tabela me mostra todas as combinações entre as 4 peças e a soma dos atributos.

Dataset de freio:

```
|Level|Freio|Força|Aero|Grip|Rely|
|:----|:----|:----|:---|:---|:---|
|  8  |MINI |8    |13  |28  |5   |
|  10 |Fth  |8    |6   |28  |11  |
```

Data set de Cambio:

```
|Level|Cambio|Força|Aero|Grip|Rely|
|:----|:-----|:----|:---|:---|:---|
|  10 |Sd    |8    |6   |6   |16  |
|  8  |Smoke |15   |5   |5   |5   |
```

Resultado esperado

Dataset esperado

```
|Combinacao|Freio|Cambio|Força|Aero|Grip|Rely|
|:---------|:----|:-----|:----|:---|:---|:---|
|Mini Sd   |Mini |Sd    |16   |19  |34  |21  |
|Mini Smoke|Mini |Smoke |23   |18  |33  |10  |
|Fth Smoke |Fth  |Smoke |23   |11  |33  |16  |
|Fth Sd    |Fth  |Sd    |16   |12  |34  |27  |
```

Comment: Você pode descrever melhor o que você quer fazer?

Comment: Claro, me ajude a enteder se fui claro. Tenho dois datasets (freio e cambio). Tanto os freios quanto os cambios possuem atributos (Força, Aero, Grip e Rely). Eu gostaria de obter o total de combinações entre esses datasets, e a soma de seus atributos.
No exemplo acima coloquei os dois datasets com duas peças cada e também uma exemplo de como gostaria de visualizar o resultado na tabela "Resultado esperado". Essa tabela me mostra todas as combinações entre as 4 peças e a soma dos atributos.

Comment: Ótimo. Por favor, clique em "editar" na pergunta e adicione essa descrição.

Comment: Feito, por favor, me avise se ficou melhor dessa maneira. Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução para esse tipo de problema é `DataFrame.combine` (link para [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html)), mas como você quer combinar colunas com nomes diferentes e fazer uma "distributiva" é preciso um pequeno workaround. Segue código:

```py
import pandas as pd 

df1=pd.read_csv("data1.txt")
df2=pd.read_csv("data2.txt")

def my_sum(a,b):
    return a+b

dfp1=df1.set_index("Level").combine(df2.set_index("Level"), my_sum).drop(['Freio','Cambio'], axis=1)
lista_dfs=[df1.set_index("Level")[['Freio']],df2.set_index("Level")[['Cambio']]]
dfp1=dfp1.join(lista_dfs)
dfp1['Combinacao']=[dfp1['Freio'][k]+' '+dfp1['Cambio'][k] for k in dfp1.index]
dfp1=dfp1.reindex(['Combinacao', 'Freio', 'Cambio', 'Força','Aero','Grip','Rely'], axis=1)

df1.Level.replace({8:10,10:8},inplace=True)
dfp2=df2.set_index("Level").combine(df1.set_index("Level"), my_sum).drop(['Freio','Cambio'], axis=1)
lista_dfs=[df2.set_index("Level")[['Cambio']],df1.set_index("Level")[['Freio']]]
dfp2=dfp2.join(lista_dfs)
dfp2['Combinacao']=[dfp2['Freio'][k]+' '+dfp2['Cambio'][k] for k in dfp2.index]
dfp2=dfp2.reindex(['Combinacao', 'Freio', 'Cambio', 'Força','Aero','Grip','Rely'], axis=1)

df=dfp1.append(dfp2).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Retorna:

```
   Combinacao Freio Cambio  Força  Aero  Grip  Rely
0  MINI Smoke  MINI  Smoke     23    18    33    10
1      Fth Sd   Fth     Sd     16    12    34    27
2     MINI Sd  MINI     Sd     16    19    34    21
3   Fth Smoke   Fth  Smoke     23    11    33    16
```

Se você pretende fazer esse procedimento muitas vezes recomendo depurar o código e criar uma função.